# application went down spree rails with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, spree, ruby-on-rails-4.2

we are working with `rails4` application with `spree 3.1.0`, we tried to optimise the code and did that but there are some third parties API which we are using for payment which took time.
when load increases into our server and as you guys know if any request goes more than 30 sec and due to that application goes down, so my question is,  is there any way by which we can terminate that request which took the time to avoid server down? I am not expert with Heroku server but know most of the thing which we can do with Heroku to manage the application

- Is there anything in rails by which we can terminate such request to avoid server down condition.
- Is there anything with Heroku by which we can handle such condition.

Comment: you can use rack-timeout which will let you configure a timeout and requests will be terminated rather than H12'ing and then continuing to run in a 'disconnected state'

Comment: this is already there but still having issue :(